# "Mortarboard" continues to be awarded on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

On Meta Stack Overflow I found badge "Mortarboard" continuing to be awarded.

It is a bug, isn't it?
What is it for, then?

Comment: Nope. You get it because your score matches what would otherwise have given you the required rep.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Badges can be awarded on child metas. And are.

In this case, though there is no associated reputation, the **aggregate** scores are what's giving these badges out (so, 20 upvotes on answers, for instance, which would on a **main** site equate to 200 reputation, would award one a mortarboard on the first time that happens).

Comment: Seems like a bug, rejected with *"will not fix."*

Comment: @ypercube - one mans bug is another ones feature. The creation of a dedicated meta for Stack Overflow is not something that will ever happen again (every other Stack Exchange site has its own Meta already). It is done - there is nothing more to fix.

Comment: I would close a bug on a thing that will never happen again as "won't fix", not as "by design", but that's just me. In the end the difference is only about the message, anyway.