# Should Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges be available on Meta sites?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta, daily-reputation-badges

*For the sake of simplicity, I will only refer to Mortarboard in this post, but every time I state it, it is also referring to Epic and Legendary*

The other day I was awarded the [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=235463) badge here on Meta. This confused me, as you of course can't gain any rep on a Meta site. So I did some research, and one of the first things I found was this question: ["Mortarboard" continues to be awarded on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251249/mortarboard-continues-to-be-awarded-on-meta-stack-overflow). One of the tags are [status-bydesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-bydesign).

But I must ask the question: Why? It feels unnecessary, given Meta can't effect your reputation anyways.

Is there any explanation of why we have it here on Meta?

Comment: Doesn't [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251249/mortarboard-continues-to-be-awarded-on-meta-stack-overflow#comment9983_251251) on the answer to the question you linked to answer your question (Note that Oded was an SO dev): "one mans bug is another ones feature. The creation of a dedicated meta for Stack Overflow is not something that will ever happen again (every other Stack Exchange site has its own Meta already). It is done - there is nothing more to fix."

Comment: I mean, there should be a reward for writing good meta posts. I've gotten mortarboard, and am on the way to earn the epic badge. There should be a reward for participating on a meta site.

Answer (score 10):

Meta is just a concept. There is no difference in the logic of the Q/A engine for every little nit bit that should or shouldn't work the same between Main and Meta. Maintaining one decent version of the Q/A engine is enough of an headache already. Adding an extra layer with a zillion feature flags to "configure" a Meta site properly is just a waste of time.

There is no harm that, under the hood, a per-site [Meta **does** have reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234775/158100). You'll only notice once you get a few badges for achieving stuff you didn't consider possible.

Enjoy your badges! (At least I can say I'm [legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary) here ...)

Now consider [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). That is a main site with a lot of Meta characteristics. Its reputation is "real" though.

Comment: There are a lot of badges that I got pretty easily on Meta, but are almost impossible on the main site. For example, "Popular Question". Because there are less questions here, it's easier to get more views. I don't participate in Meta just for badges, but it certainly is a great side reward!