# How did a user with less than 5 reputation write an answer on meta?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I recently saw [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407500/12708583) [(screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgJ2t.png)). It was written by a user with exactly 1 reputation and no reputation changes (see their [reputation history - there are no changes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15865724/jentci?tab=reputation)).

The question itself was not migrated from the main site, and no other shenanigans happened.

I thought 5 reputation was [required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) to post an answer on meta.

Did the user gain 5 [invisible reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406258/12708583) on meta and then get the privilege to post? Or is this a bug?

Comment: @Ivar this user posted an answer, not a question. And if not, there should be an indication that they are part of a team.

Comment: "Starting with the latest build, an un-suspended Stack Overflow user who is an active member of a Team **can post to Meta Stack Overflow even if they have < 5 reputation.**" They never specified.

Comment: There should be an indication or something. Gaining 5 reputation isn't that hard anyways... why can't someone who is in a team gain that much and then post?

Comment: The question is: why should they? They are forced to go to MSO to report an issue, so it isn't clever to add more restrictions.

Comment: Maybe they should go through, iunno, customer support, rather than dumping it on the community support area.

Comment: It would actually make sense to do this only to questions, taking in count the rationale behind it... A Teams member is forced to ask a question on MSO - ok. No one is forcing them to post an answer... Answers should still have the same restrictions (as evident by the example answer above)

Comment: I mean, until spam from this specific (and theoretically small) group of users becomes a problem, I don't think there's anything to complain about here. If 5 rep. is truly trivial to obtain, then it really shouldn't matter if they have it or not. Besides, we have a [[tag:stack-overflow-for-teams]] tag precisely *for* discussion/ support/ feature-requests/ bugs related to teams; this *is* an official support channel. Forcing a teams user to get *x* rep. (however small) to ask for help would be hilariously poor UX.

Comment: I get that this case is an answer, rather than question, but I personally don't think this is worth dev attention unless it becomes more of a problem.